# jquery ajax page content filling

Tags: jquery, ajax

what is the best practice of such workflow?

As example, I have following html page structure:

```html
<div id="one">
    <span id="sp1"></span>
    <span id="sp2"></span>
    ...
    <div id="inner"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

And use following jquery code for filling html data into div #one:

```js
$.get('/scripts/contajax.php', function(data){

    var addhtml = data,
        sp1cont = addhtml.replace(/.*<sp1>(.*)</sp1>.*/,'$1'),
        sp2cont = addhtml.replace(/.*<sp2>(.*)</sp2>.*/,'$1'),
        inncont = addhtml.replace(/.*<inn>(.*)</inn>.*/,'$1');

    $('#sp1').html(sp1cont);
    $('#sp2').html(sp2cont);
    $('#inner').html(inncont);

});
```

Basically, /scripts/contajax.php generates html code:
   `<sp1>...</sp1><sp2>...</sp2><inn>...</inn>`

and then query parses this code and insert chunks into HTML page.
Am I using right approach? or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

JSON and XML are the best ones for this job.

Since I don't know very much about how to deal with XML, I'm gonna try to explain JSON usage.

In your `contajax.php`, fill your array with appropriate data:

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray["sp1"] = "sp1Content"; // no html tags, just values
$myArray["sp2"] = "sp2Content";
$myArray["inn"] = "innContent";
```

and so on. After that print your array as json:

```
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

In your script, call `.getJSON()` instead `.get()` and insert values into html like that:

```
$.getJSON('/scripts/contajax.php', function(data){
   $('#sp1').html(data.sp1);
   $('#sp2').html(data.sp2);
   $('#inner').html(data.inn);
}
```

You can see `data` in console any time by calling `JSON.stringify(data);` in function of `getJSON`